# How to use glm::isnan()

Tags: c++, glm-math

I can't get glm::isnan() to compile in my Visual C++ project.

```
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

glm::vec3 my_vector = ... ;

bool b = glm::isnan(my_vector);
```

The last line causes the following compilation error:

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'glm::detail::tvec3' to 'bool'

According to documentation it returs true or false.

Comment: Maybe for a single number it returns true or false. For a vector it apparently returns a vector, and you try to assign it to a boolean variable.

Answer (score 2):

The GLM 0.9.9 documentation for `glm::isnan` can be found at https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00662.html. It says that the return type is `vec<L, bool, Q>`, so you can use `glm::all` like so:

```cpp
bool b = glm::all(glm::isnan(my_vector));
```

to check if all components of `my_vector` are NaN.